# How to Find Confusion Matrix and Plot for my Model in Pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch, transfer-learning

I Have trained a resnet-09 model for emotion classification in images But I cannot find a way to get the confusion matrix for my test-set this is the model code

```
  def conv_block(in_channels, out_channels, pool=False):
  layers = [nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1), 
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
  if pool: layers.append(nn.MaxPool2d(2))
  return nn.Sequential(*layers)

class ResNet(ImageClassificationBase):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, num_classes):
      super().__init__()
      
      self.input = conv_block(in_channels, 64)

      self.conv1 = conv_block(64, 64, pool=True)
      self.res1 = nn.Sequential(conv_block(64, 32), conv_block(32, 64))
      self.drop1 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
      
      self.conv2 = conv_block(64, 64, pool=True)
      self.res2 = nn.Sequential(conv_block(64, 32), conv_block(32, 64))
      self.drop2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
      
      self.conv3 = conv_block(64, 64, pool=True)
      self.res3 = nn.Sequential(conv_block(64, 32), conv_block(32, 64))
      self.drop3 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
      
      self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.MaxPool2d(6), 
                                      nn.Flatten(),
                                      nn.Linear(64, num_classes))
      
  def forward(self, xb):
      out = self.input(xb)

      out = self.conv1(out)
      out = self.res1(out) + out
      out = self.drop1(out)
      
      out = self.conv2(out)
      out = self.res2(out) + out
      out = self.drop2(out)
      
      out = self.conv3(out)
      out = self.res3(out) + out
      out = self.drop3(out)
      
      return self.classifier(out)
```

this was my data Preperation

```
data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset'
print(os.listdir(data_dir))
classes_train = os.listdir(data_dir + "/train")
classes_valid = os.listdir(data_dir + "/validation")
print(f'Train Classes - {classes_train}')
print(f'Validation Classes - {classes_valid}')
```

I'm Using google Colab I don't know how to find y_true y_pred to build a confusion Matrix

Comment: Is your question about (a) how to retrieve values of `y_true` and `y_val`, or (b) How to build a confusion matrix?

Comment: Both , i have trained this model and i want to build a confusion matrix